# Why is de testrunner crashing after converting my solution to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, mstest

After I converted a solution to Visual Studio 2012 (previous version was Visual Studio 2010) I tried to run the unit tests in the solution. Now the testrunner crashes before executing a single test. I get a rather general error message. If I choose to debug Visual Studio I get the following stack trace:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TMI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.AssemblyKeyExtractor.ExtractPublicKeyFromKeyFile(string keyFile, out bool isPublicKey)
[Managed to Native Transition]
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TMI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.PublicKeyHolder.this[string].get(string file)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TMI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.DeploymentHelper.GetPublicKey(string keyFile, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.PublicKeyHolder publicKeyHolder)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TMI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.DeploymentHelper.ProcessCodeCoverageItemsForDeployment(System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.DeploymentCoverageItem> deploymentCoverageItems)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TMI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.DeploymentManager.DoDeployment(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestRun run, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.FileCopyService fileCopyService)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TMI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy.SetupTestRun(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestRun run, bool isNewTestRun, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.FileCopyService fileCopyService, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.DeploymentManager deploymentManager)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TMI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy.SetupRunAndListener(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestRun run, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.FileCopyService fileCopyService, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.DeploymentManager deploymentManager)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TMI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy.QueueTestRunWorker(object state)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

The stack trace suggest that the fact that I am testing a signed assembly may trigger the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I discovered that I could solve this problem by disabling code coverage for the test run in the test run configuration file. You can do this by opening the LocalTestRun.testrunconfig file (located under solution items) -> Data and Diagnostics then disable 'Code coverage (Visual Studio 2010)'